# How to configure IPTables to accept http from a single IP in inbound direction and allow DNS in outgoing direction and block?

Tags: iptables

I am trying to configure IPTables to accept http connection from 10.0.0.1 only and reject everything else. When I make http connection from 10.0.0.1, it is blocked.  I am facing another issue. I am trying to allow DNS in outgoing direction and block everything else. The problem is when I use OUTPUT DROP everything is dropped

Here is what I did

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: What did/did-not work?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor When I make http connection from 10.0.0.1, it is blocked

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted. Please edit question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have blocked output as well (remove the last two lines).
The source port will not be 80. You should have configured `--dport 80`.

Consider also using `ufw` or `gufw`(a graphical front end to `ufw`). As these can do this for you, and are much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

With `iptables` rules, the order matters.
If 10.0.0.1 is the **client** connecting to an HTTP server, what you need is `--dport` (destination port), not *source* port.
So:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

The second rule means: drop everything else.

Comment: While order does matter. What has this to do with the rest of your answer. There was nothing wrong with the order, and you have not changed it. Did you mean direction?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor He meant direction and OUTPUT DROP blocks everything, even in inbound direction

Comment: @Anonymous I am facing another issue. I am trying to allow DNS in outgoing direction and block everything else. The problem is when I use OUTPUT DROP everything is dropped

Comment: To allow incoming DNS, something like this: `iptables -A INPUT  --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`. Note that I deliberately omitted `-p UDP` in the rule, because some DNS traffic may require TCP (for example zone transfers). `iptables -P INPUT DROP` should be the last rule since it blocks anything else that is not explicitly authorized. If you decide to also restrict outgoing traffic you would need something like: `iptables -A OUTPUT --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @Anonymous but I need to block everything in outgoing direction except for DNS

Comment: @hosam.shafik please do not explain for others. I think I have as good an idea of what Anonymous is saying as you do. I don't need your help to get the wrong idea. I am capable of that my self. The purpose of my comment is to point out an ambiguity, not to get help from 3rd parties.